# Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Cuando trabajo con code first cuando tengo una propiedad de navegación y trabajo con Map, esa propiedad de navegación ¿es sólo para el código?

Otra pregunta, mi clave primaria es un string ProveedorId, ¿cómo le digo a EF que mi PK no es identity?

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public string ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string RUC { get; set; }
    public string DNI { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Fijo { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public string Representante { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }

}
```

Map

```
public class ProveedorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Proveedor>
{
    public ProveedorMap()
    {
        ToTable("Proveedores");
        HasKey(c => c.ProveedorId);
        Property(c => c.ProveedorId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6).HasColumnOrder(0)
        Property(c => c.RazonSocial).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200).HasColumnOrder(1);
        Property(c => c.RUC).HasMaxLength(11).HasColumnOrder(2);
        Property(c => c.DNI).HasMaxLength(8).HasColumnOrder(3);
        Property(c => c.Direccion).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(4);
        Property(c => c.Fijo).HasMaxLength(9).HasColumnOrder(5);
        Property(c => c.Celular).HasMaxLength(9).HasColumnOrder(6);
        Property(c => c.Representante).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(7);
        Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(8);

    }
}
```

La propiedad de navegación no va en ProveedorMap.

Comment: si tu ID va a ser string... te recomendaria que lo hagas GUID

Comment: Hola fredyfx, como declaras una atributo como tipo de dato GUID? a que te refieres como GUID?

Comment: lo que se busca que es sea un dato único cierto? revisa: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_único_global y para definirlo en C# a lo que tienes sería: public Guid ProveedorId { get; set; }

Comment: Poniendolo como GUID abarca muchos tipos de datos entre ellos esta el string, lo voy a probar.

Comment: Con GUID no se puede poner un tamaño al atributo ProveedorId por ejemplo quiero que sea tamaño de 6, en string si puedo hacer eso

Comment: Esto puede ser un GUID 000001, 000002

Comment: Esta demostrado que un GUID no es único https://datafull.co/p/prueba-simple-que-guid-no-es-unico

Comment: Esos  "000001, 000002"  no puede ser un GUID. Revisa aquí: https://www.guidgenerator.com y eso que dices que está demostrado que un GUID no es único... Has leído todo el contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>cuando tengo una propiedad de navegacion y trabajo con Map esa propiedad de navegacion es solo para el código?**

Imagino te refieres a la definicion del las propiedades que lista los productos, en ese caso tendrias

```
 public class Producto {

      public int ProductoId { get; set; }

      //resto propiedades

      public string ProveedorId { get; set; }
      public Proveedor Proveedor{ get; set; }

 }
```

Esas propiedad ProveedorId que permiten unir en una relacion `uno a mucho` si son solo para el Id

pero la propiedad

```
 public ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
```

de la clase `Proveedor` esa contendra las entidades de los productos completa

**>>mi clave primaria es un string ProveedorId, como le digo a EF que mi PK no es identity?**

No puedes, es mas intenta hacer esto en la base de datos, veras que el campos que quieras definir como identity solo puedes ser numerico

**>>La propiedad de navegación no va en ProveedorMap.**

Si tambien puedes definirla

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Asociación uno a muchos (1/3)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/07/entity-frameworkcode-first-asociacion.html)

para eso usas el `HasRequired` o `HasOptional` como explico en el articulo

Comment: Leandro, ProveedorId es string, además como no le estoy diciendo a EF que es Identity entonces me supongo que no lo hara identity. Asi es Leandro es una relación uno a muchos, revisare tu articulo.

Comment: Leandro, en que casos puede ser HasOptional, por que si hay un Foren Key es por que se quiere integridad referencial de datos.

Comment: Leandro en la Entidad Producto la propiedad de navegación tambien puede ir de la siguiente manera. public virtual Proveedor ProveedorAsignado {get; set;} o public virtual Proveedor Proveedor {get; set;} veo que no usas virtual a que se debe?

Comment: Solo defini un ejemplo, si la propiedad de navegacion puede llevar otro nombre si asi lo necesitas. El virtual me olvide de agregarlo.